# AS3 URLLoader unable to find local file

Tags: actionscript-3, file-not-found, urlrequest

Using AS3 Loader object's load(new URLRequest('file.swf'), and the file is in the same directory as the FLA file. Just read that flash looks for files based on the application directory, but even when using the absolute file path flash can't find it such as  "C:\Users\acerbook\Desktop\swf2\file.swf".

i keep getting "Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:." and "Error #2035: URL Not Found.", seemingly regardless

Edit: Tested with adobe's preloader files and it worked, so there must be some issue with my AS, will keep checking.

Comment: Is this an AIR Project or regular Flash project for Web?

Comment: Oh, it's a web flash project. Also forgot to say that it looks like the file somehow loads, at least the graphic's there, but the swf flickers, and gives the aforementioned errors.

Comment: added an edit to question.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of your code?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Day 2 things are clearer, for one I forgot to set output file to the sub directory, but now there's a separate error, thanks for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You did read wrong, files are loaded from the location of the generated swf file or the generated html file (if running inside a html), files are NEVER loaded according to the project directory location. If you have set your swf to be exported to a different folder then loading operations run from that location.

The absolute path you are using is not a valid url and so a URLRequest can't find it.

Comment: yea, i figured that from adobe's example file, thanks for the info.